# FIPS reject html to pdf conversion using SelectPdf Html To Pdf Converter for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, fips, selectpdf

I can convert HTML to pdf using SelectPDF. When I enable FIPS in my system. It shows one error like

> Could not create the PdfDocument object. This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.

We can forcefully disable FIPS in our system using

> enforceFIPSPolicy enabled="false"

But I want it to convert HTML to PDF using SelectPdf Html To Pdf Converter for .NET with after enabling FIPS. Do we have any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SelectPdf latest version 18.4 works with FIPS if no security settings are set for the PDF.